# Manipulate, IF statements, and displaying plots

Tags: plotting, manipulate, conditional

When using manipulate and plotting a function within an IF statement, curly brackets appear in the panle with the displayed plot.  Here is a simple version of the issue.  Can someone tell how to suppress the brackets?  Thanks!

```
Manipulate[
 stable = True;
 If[stable,
  {
   p1 = Plot[Sin[\[Alpha] u], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotStyle -> Blue];
   p2 = Plot[Sin[\[Beta] u], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotStyle -> Red];
   Show[{p1, p2}]
   },
  {
   p3 = Plot[Cos[\[Alpha] u], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> Medium];
   p4 = Plot[Cos[\[Beta] u], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> Medium];
   Show[{p3, p4}]
   }],
 (* Define parameters and create sliders *)
 Style["Testing Plots within IF Statement ", Bold, 20],
 Delimiter, Style["Parameters", Bold, 14], {{\[Alpha], 1, Style["Frequency 1", 12]}, 1, 10, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled", BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 12}, {{\[Beta], 2, Style["Frequency 2", 12]}, 1, 
10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled", BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 12},

 TrackedSymbols :> {\[Alpha], \[Beta]}, SynchronousUpdating -> False, 
 ControlType -> Slider, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> curly brackets appear in the panle with the displayed plot

Well, this is because you had them there. There is no need for them. You had this

```
 If[stable,{..; ;..},{..; ;..}]
```

You can just used

```
 If[stable,..;..;..,..;...]
```

I also removed the `{}` inside Show. Not needed. i.e. replace

```
 Show[{p3, p4}]
```

with just

```
  Show[p3, p4]
```

And it still works.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Manipulate[stable = True;
 If[stable,
  p1 = Plot[Sin[α u], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotStyle -> Blue];
  p2 = Plot[Sin[β u], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotStyle -> Red];
  Show[p1, p2]
  ,      
  p3 = Plot[Cos[α u], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> Medium];
  p4 = Plot[Cos[β u], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> Medium];
  Show[p3, p4]
  ]
 ,

 (*Define parameters and create sliders*)
 Style["Testing Plots within IF Statement ", Bold, 20], Delimiter, 
 Style["Parameters", Bold, 14],{{α, 1, Style["Frequency 1", 12]}, 1, 10, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled", BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 12},
 {{β, 2, Style["Frequency 2", 12]}, 1, 10, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled", BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 12},
 TrackedSymbols :> {α, β},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 ControlType -> Slider, ControlPlacement -> Left
 ]
```